# PHP + Windows 7 + AMPPS: [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and AMPPS. I am trying a very simple file upload screen using this example:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

1. The HTML asks user to upload a file.
2. Then the Action Calls and "uploader.php".
3. This uploader.php is supposed to move a file from source to target.
4. file_uploads = On  // In PHP INI file
5. upload_tmp_dir = "C:\Users\t_dutta\Documents\Projects\AMPPS\Domains\test-domain2\tempfiles"
6. The time stamp of temp directory above does get updated every time I run the HTML form.
7. In the code, I have pasted various versions of copy function I tried.

## HTML Form (form.html) code:

```
<form action="php/uploader.php" method="post"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
```

## PHP Code (uploader.php):

```
<?php
$file_path = "\\temp";
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
$path = $root . "\\finalfiles\\";
$real_path = realpath($path);

if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" )
{    
    echo $_FILES['file']['name'] . "<p></p>";
    echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "<p></p>";
    echo $real_path . "<p></p>";

//Copy Function 1st Version
copy ($_FILES['file']['name'], $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) or 
die("<p>Could not copy file!</p>");

//Copy Function 2nd Version
//copy ($_FILES['file']['name'], $root) or 
//     die("<p>Could not copy file!</p>");

//Copy Function 3rd Version
//copy ($_FILES['file']['name'], $path) or 
//     die("<p>Could not copy file!</p>");

//Copy Function 4th Version
//copy ($_FILES['file']['name'],"C:\Users\t_dutta\Documents\Projects\AMPPS\
//Domains\test-domain2\finalfiles") or die("<p>Could not copy file!</p>");

 }
   else
   {
       die("No file specified!");
   }
   ?>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Uploading Complete</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h2>Uploaded File Info:</h2>
   <ul>
   <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'];  ?>
   <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['size'];  ?> bytes
   <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['type'];  ?>
   </ul>
   </body>
   </html>
```

## Error Message:

```
PN.txt
C:/Users/t_dutta/Documents/Projects/AMPPS/Domains/test-domain2
C:\Users\t_dutta\Documents\Projects\AMPPS\Domains\test-domain2\finalfiles

Warning: copy(PN.txt) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\t_dutta\Documents\Projects\AMPPS\Domains\test-domain2\php\uploader.php on line 13
Could not copy file!
```

Comment: Check (echo) `$_FILES['file']['size']` also - I suspect it might tell you `0`

Comment: If I comment out copy(), the rest of the PHP execution follows and correctly displays file name, size and type. I have tried it for different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now managed to fix the problem. The problem was indeed related to the parameters I passed to copy function as you indicated.

I first changed the code from copy() to move_uploaded_file(). Then changed 1st argument from " $_FILES['file']['name'] " to " $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ". Then I modified the target path (in the 2nd argument) to how you suggested.

I built the target path this way (on Windows):

$path = $root . "\" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']) ;

Additional code: move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)

where $path = $root . "\" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']) ;

And it Worked !!!  Thanks a lot for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
// put this line after $root declaration (after line 2)
$target = $root . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

// replace copy() function with this
(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target))
```

The `move_uploaded_file` function is more relevant than using `copy()`

[Read more about it here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Awesome! If it helped, please accept the answer - any more questions, fire away!

Comment: Hey Darren, I have now managed to fix the problem. The problem was indeed related to the parameters I passed to copy function.    I first changed the code from copy() to move_uploaded_file(). Then changed 1st argument from " $_FILES['file']['name'] " to " $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ". Then I modified the target path (in the 2nd argument) to how you suggested. I built the target path this way (on Windows):    $path = $root . "\\" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']) ;    And it Worked !!!    Thanks a lot for your help !!!

Comment: Ha ha. I am struggling with line breaks in my last comment !!! Anyway let me go ahead and accept this as a solution.